# Cannot POST object from React to Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I cannot POST an object from my React frontend to Spring Boot.
I'm receiving this error `Cannot deserialize value of type java.lang.String from Object value (token JsonToken.START_OBJECT)]`
This is the API endpoint

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerUser(@RequestBody RegistrationDTO body){
    ....
}
```

This is my DTO that I'm expecting as a body

```
public class RegistrationDTO {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //getters, setters, constructors...
}
```

Now this is the React frontend code...

```
const registerUser = async (name, phone, email, password) => {

const apiEndpoint = 'http://localhost:8000/auth/register'

const req = {        
    name:name,
    phone:phone,
    username:email,
    password:password
}


const customConfig = {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

try {
    const resp = await axios.post(apiEndpoint, req, customConfig)
    return resp.data
} catch (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
    return null
}
```

}

Comment: What does the actual JSON look like? Are the values for each of the fields (name, phone, username, password) indeed strings or are one or more of them an object (something between `{ ... }`)?

Comment: the problem is most likely that the json you are sending doesn't match (and hence can't be deserialized to) `RegistrationDTO`. Show us the JSON you are sending - you can find it in the `Network` tab in chrome, in `Request Payload` section

Comment: They're all strings.

Comment: I didn't know about Network-Request payload --- thank you. my JSON was wrong